# Strange behaviour with JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This is a strange thing I have noticed, I don't remember it ever being a problem in the past.

Within Google Chrome (47.0.2526.106 m) objects seem to not be passed to other variables as they should. So below is a snippet of code I have been testing this with and the expected result:

**Expected result**

```
var myobj = {
    count: 5
};

console.log(myobj) // will log something like object(count: 5)
console.log(myobj['count']) // 5

var anotherobj = myobj;

console.log(anotherobj) // will log something like object(count: 5)
console.log(anotherobj['count']) // 5
```

The above is what I remember being the case as objects are passed as references so you still get the data but under another 'name', what seems to actually happen is below:

**Actual result*

```
var myobj = {
    count: 5
};

console.log(myobj) // will log something like object(count: 5)
console.log(myobj['count']) // 5

var anotherobj = myobj;

console.log(anotherobj) // [object Object] <- this seems to be a string
console.log(anotherobj['count']) // undefined
```

I don't see what is happening, is this a bug is the recent version of Chrome or am I just having some strange imaginative thought thinking that this used to be possible??

Thanks for your help in advanced :)

Comment: What method are you using to test this in google chrome?  Is there anything else relevant going on?

Comment: Are u writing `console.log` on chrome's console ?

Comment: I've tested in Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m console, and it gives me the expected results (i.e. `Object {count: 5}` for `console.log(anotherobj)`

Comment: @FrobberOfBits I tested it inside a JS file and then run it on a page. Inside Chrome's dev tools the same happens. No other code is being run other than what I added in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I just had another look and I think I made a typo in my code somewhere. I used what I wrote in my question and it worked fine. Been trying to work this out for about half an hour. How did I not see that it was just a typo??

Think I need sleep :P

Comment: If Chrome were to introduce such a bug, then the entire web would stop functioning. If you found a typo, then instead of posting an answer, please delete your question.